# OpenGL - first person camera

Tags: opengl

I'm afraid I'm experiencing `Gimbal lock` when I'm trying to implement a first person camera in OpenGl.

```
rotateFPS_OY(float angle){
    forward = forward * cos(angle) + right * sin(angle);
    right = forward.CrossProduct(up);

}
rotateFPS_OX(float angle){
    up = up * cos(angle) + forward * sin(angle); 
    forward = up.CrossProduct(right);
}
```

Later on, I call gluLookAt:

```
    Vector3D center = position + forward;
    gluLookAt(position.x, position.y, position.z, 
              center.x, center.y, center.z,
              up.x, up.y, up.z);
```

When testing this out it seems that after a few movements, the camera rolls (changes the right vector). The calculations seem correct, I just can't tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to successfully implement the camera by keeping the forward.y and right.y on 0 and calculating a lookAt vector independently from the forward/right/up vectors.

Answer (score 0):

normalize vectors after calculating

Comment: why up = up * cos(angle) + forward * sin(angle);forward = up.CrossProduct(right)?; may be forward=forwad*cos+up*sin;up=forwardXright;  but is not solve.

Comment: Didn't work this way either, it actually turns the image backwards and still has the roll effect.

Comment: Oh. Dont rotate around up. rotate around (0,0,1).

Comment: Could you please care to explain how I can do that?

Comment: f1.x=f.x*cos-f.y*sin;f1.y=f.x*sin+f.y*cos;f1.z=f.z; f=f1; f is forward; same for right;  up=rightXforward; change rotateFPS_OY only